# PyAgrum returns a causal formula doesn't make sense / python

Tags: python, pyagrum

I'm using the pyagrum library for python, and I'm having trouble with the causal formulas the library calculates based on the network.

I have the following causal graph:
[The graph:
"L[1,3]<-G->Q[1,4];L<-C[0,3]->Q;L<-P[1,4]->Q;Q->L;G->P"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz9bw.png)

I'd like to calculate: P(L | do(G))

PyAgrum returned me:
[This equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muhw2.png)

But this backdoor on C does NOT exist, so it's definitely wrong.
I did it by myself and got this equation:
[The equation I got by hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5A4b.png)

How do I know if what I'm doing it's right? I was trusting pyagrum to correct me but now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to check why the given explanation is wrong. However, the computation is correct. And the formula also : P(L|C,G) will have to be computed using classical inference and will, give at the end, the same formula as yours (actually, in your graph, it seems that P(L|do(G))=P(L|G) )

Comment: Hello Rafaela, 
Just to let you know that I just fixed this issue in the current version (master @ https://gitlab.com/agrumery/aGrUM).

If you want to test it quickly, you can `pip install pyagrum-nightly` tomorrow.  The next release (probably 0.17.4) will arrive soon (in May).